# Eloquent - groupBy and sum() of hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models Job, Diary, Resource.
Jobs has relation with Diary and Diary has relation with Resource.
I wanted to get all Resource associated with a Job and did this using

```php
public function labourers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Resource::class, Diary::class, 'job_id');
}
```

On my Job class.

Now I want to group the results by User who's user_id is a column in Resource and then show the total hours.

This is the closest I can get.

```php
    $job = Job::where('job_number', 3007)->first();
    $labour = $job->labourers()->get();
    $results = $labour->groupBy('user_id');
    echo $results;

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $hours = $result->sum('hours');
        echo $result[0]->user_id." - ";
        echo $hours.". ";
    }
```

This gets me the user_id and the sum of the hours but I am unable to access the user name through the relationship set up on the resource model

```php
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

with

```php
$result->user->name;
```

This produces

> Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.

How can I return a collection which allows me to access the users name and the sum of the hours.

Comment: Try `$result[0]->user->name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not able to access the `user` like that is because (in this case) `groupBy` is a method on the collection that returns another collection.
Firstly, eager load the `user` relationship on so that your code is a bit more efficient:

```
$labour = $job->labourers()->with('user')->get();
```

Secondly, since you have a collection you can use `first()` instead of `[0]`:

```
$result->first()->user_id
```

Lastly, you would have to access the `user` in the same way you're accessing the `user_id`:

```
$result->first()->user
```

So, you would end up with something like:

```
$job = Job::where('job_number', 3007)->first();
$labourers = $job->labourers()->with('user')->get();
$results = $labourers->groupBy('user_id');

foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->first()->user->name . ' - ' . $result->sum('hours') . '.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this

```
$job = Job::where('job_number', 3007)->with(['labourers' => function($query){
    $query->select('id','user_id', DB::raw('sum(hours) as hours'))->groupBy('user_id');
 }, labourers.user])->first();

 $results = $job->labourers;

 foreach($results as $result){
    print_r($result->user);
    print_r($result->hours);
 }
```